# GoLang chaining io.Reader

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a proxy pattern to chain transformations on io.Reader, in order to handle chunk of bytes efficiently.

1. We cannot use pointers on receivers, so my solution seem not very efficient
2. The code below say "process take too long"

Complete example at: https://play.golang.org/p/KhM0VXLq4CO

```
b := bytes.NewBufferString(text)
t := transformReaderHandler(*b)
readByChunk(t)

type transformReaderHandler bytes.Buffer

func (t transformReaderHandler) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = (*bytes.Buffer)(&t).Read(p)
    //if n > 0 {
    //  Do Something on the chunk
    //}
    return
}
```

Do you have any more efficient (memory efficient, computationally efficient) solution ?

Why do this code is not working ?

EDIT:
The implementation of @svsd solution : https://play.golang.org/p/VUpJcyKLB6D

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

const text = "Reaaaaally long and complex text to read in chunk"

func main() {
    b := bytes.NewBufferString(text)

    t := (*transformReaderHandler)(b)

    readByChunk(t)
}

type transformReaderHandler bytes.Buffer

func (t *transformReaderHandler) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = (*bytes.Buffer)(t).Read(p)
    if n > 0 {
        p[0] = 'X'
    }
    return
}

func readByChunk(r io.Reader) {
    var p = make([]byte, 4)

    for {
        n, err := r.Read(p)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(string(p[:n]))
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do not convert back to the original type, it will call the Read method of "transformReaderHandler" and crash in a stack overflow. You can try it yourself in the playground : https://play.golang.org/p/KhM0VXLq4CO

Comment: You should make `transformReaderHandler` be a struct that embeds `bytes.Buffer`. Then you can call `t.Buffer.Read(p)` instead of your ugly type conversion.

Comment: Yes, right, but it would involve a struct creation, my original though was to do like net/http.HandlerFunc() is doing.

Comment: @Shengis: what do you mean by "a struct creation"? What `HanderFunc` is doing is something different.

Comment: What you do in your code, "&transformReaderHandler{b}" is creating a new object. I believe, HandlerFunc is not creating a new object, it use dynamic bindings to call his version of ServeHTTP.

Comment: "We cannot use pointers on receivers" why not? That would be the correct implementation.

Comment: I cannot do a "type transformReaderHandler *bytes.Buffer" or I will get error : invalid receiver type *transformReaderHandler (transformReaderHandler is a pointer type)

Comment: @Shengis: there are no "objects" or "dynamic bindings" in go. A struct with only an embedded `bytes.Buffer` is exactly the same memory layout as the `bytes.buffer` itself.

Comment: @JimB, ok thanks for the info, I thought it was kinda like in C++ ; so method calls are always resolved at compile time ?

Comment: @Shengis: yes, all methods are known at compile time. You can do runtime checks with type assertions, but regardless of which dynamic type you get from an interface, the code itself is compiled to static types and method calls.

Comment: I implemented the two methods for benchmarking purpose. I got 266 ns/op not using struct, 306 ns/op using struct. If someone know why, I'm interested.

Comment: @Shengis: you would have to inspect the assembly and look at the various optimizations made by the compiler you used. 40ns difference is not a lot for something like a `Read` call which is usually quite expensive, and the outcome can change between different compiler releases. Choosing the code based on micro-optimizations is rarely useful when it is dependent on specific go versions -- use whichever version makes the code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code below say "process take too long"
>
> Why do this code is not working ?

In the `transformReaderHandler.Read()` method, you have a value receiver. That means each time `Read()` is called, it gets a **copy** of the instance on which it was called. Then when you then call `(*bytes.Buffer)(&t).Read(p)`, it modifies the internal state of that instance so that next time when you read, it reads from after the point it read earlier.

Now because the instance is a copy, it is discarded after the method exits and the original instance remains unchanged. Hence, each time you call `Read()`, `bytes.Buffer.Read()` reads only the first few bytes. To prove this, add a statement `fmt.Println("n=", n, "err=", err)` inside `readByChunk()` after calling `Read()`.

To quickly check that this is indeed due to the value receiver, you can define `transformReaderHandler.Read()` with a pointer receiver and store `t` as `t = (*transformReaderHandler)(b)`. I'll let you examine what it does. (edit: the correct solution involving embedding is in the comments)

> Do you have any more efficient (memory efficient, computationally efficient) solution ?

If you're only looking for buffered IO for more efficient reads, look at the [`bufio.NewReader()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader). If that's not sufficient, you can take inspiration from it and wrap around an `io.Reader` interface instead of wrapping over a `bytes.Buffer` instance.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is insightful !

Answer (score 4):

You're copying the `bytes.Buffer` value each time `Read` is called on the `transformReaderHandler`, so you can never progress through the buffer. You must used a `*bytes.Buffer` pointer to avoid this copy.

Embed the buffer (or alternatively add it as a named field) in your `transformReaderHandler`, so you can call delegate the `Read` method as needed.

```
type transformReaderHandler struct {
    *bytes.Buffer
}

func (t *transformReaderHandler) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = t.Buffer.Read(p)
    //if n > 0 {
    //  Do Something
    //}
    return
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/npZQ4Tz0hhv